# Cakephp 3.0 Multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm sure I am just being an idiot, but can anyone help?, the following controller is only saving to the users table, not the child "Userapikey" table (All other data is auto built by Cakephp and MySQL):

```
$data = $this->request->data;
// Create the default access mask
$data[ 'userapikey' ] = [
    [ 'accessmask' => 22966271 ]
];

// Create a new entity in the DB and populate
$User = $this->Users->newEntity( $data, [ 'associated' => [ 'Userapikeys' ]  );

// Commit to the database
if( $this->Users->save( $User ) ) {
// Blah Blah send message etc.
}
```

UserTable.php has got the

```
$this->hasMany('Userapikeys', [ 'foreignKey' => 'user_id' ]);
```

Userapikeys.php has the

```
$this->belongsTo('Users', [ 'foreignKey' => 'user_id' ]);
```

If you need any more information I would be happy to provide

Comment: P.S I have already raked through all the CakePHP 3.0 documentation and several other people's issues but to no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually found that in the User.php entity please make sure the accessible included your "child" table eg.

```
protected $_accessible = [
    'username' => true,
    'password' => true,
    'user_api_keys' => true
];
```

and make sure it is the underscored version and plural

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have User hasMany UserApikeys your data array should be:

```
$data[ 'userapikeys' ][0] = [
    [ 'accessmask' => 22966271 ]
];
```

Comment: I have included this in the code and unfortunately to no success

Comment: I have also created a Gist if this helps https://gist.github.com/dystopiavirus/4697dca695ddd14ad6c3